# How to play mp3/wav/m4a without external libaries and without windows media player showing up (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I want to play a sound in python but I don't want to use external libaries like pygame and I don't want the windows media player to show up.

Its not that I can't pip install things but other people who will be using this program won't know how to pip install python libaries.

```
winsound.PlaySound(r"C:\Temp\Soundboard\s1.mp3", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

^^^ That just plays a windows sound.

`os.system("start C:\Temp\Soundboard\s1.mp3")`

^^^ And that makes windows media player pop up to play the sound.

**Any help will be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`winsound` will work fine, as long as the files are `wav` files. To play other files, I'd recommend using the [vlc.py](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated;b=HEAD). Just include the entire file (or you can attempt to separate the parts that you don't need), found [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generated/2.2/vlc.py;h=17b94eaa7928e8c9a85bb6578b6d8a153416c1ec;hb=HEAD), in your own file to use the relevant functions.

Comment: Thank you so much this has been annyoing me for ages.